# Why would I use Mandrill as opposed to the built in ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, mandrill

I've read the documentation for both services but I just am not seeing the benefits of using Mandrill as opposed to Rail's ActionMailer for transactional services. I can already customize emails with ActionMailer and send them out. Is the difference between the services a matter of volume? If so, at what point would I need to switch out ActionMailer for Mandrill?

This tutorial here is a little bit more confusing because it integrates ActionMailer with Mandrill. [MailChimp/Mandrill tutorial](http://aspiringwebdev.com/e-mail-in-rails-with-mailchimp-and-mandrill-a-comprehensive-guide/)

Can someone help me explain the difference? For my real life purpose, all I want to do is send emails to people to reverify their accounts and according to my research that would seem like a job suited for MailChimp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically mailchimp/mandrill is a Saas offering they offer you a SMTP services like the amazon SES service.
ActionMailer is a part of Rails that allow interfacing with a mailing system.

from its docs you can see the following options:

```
Defines a delivery method. Possible values are:

    :smtp (default), can be configured by using config.action_mailer.smtp_settings.
    :sendmail, can be configured by using config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings.
    :file: save emails to files; can be configured by using config.action_mailer.file_settings.
    :test: save emails to ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
```

where the default for SMTP is using localhost (assuming your own server run a SMTP server.

In your case you should use mailchimp to deliver you message, but you will still need to use actionMailer to create the message/email itself.

It reduces complexity by allowing you to offload the sending part.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that sending emails synchronously from the server is generally a bad idea (slows down the server and it's better to have a separation of concerns). It's recommended to use an external service or sending it asynchronously using `.delay` with sidekiq.

Answer (score 1):

For the use that you're describing, it sounds like action mailer is just fine.

However, if

1. You're not interested in managing a mail server
2. Don't want to spend time trying to figure out if an email was actually sent (based on a client reports)
3. Want to impose mail quotas easily per client

Then I would recommend mandrill. We've started using it for mailing and haven't looked back since. You get reliability, expert advice / mail system setup and ultimately the biggest feature for me: delivery reporting.

Mandrill allows you to interact with their system via REST API or SMTP. If you're using their SMTP, you would still need to use ActionMailer to deliver email. All you need to do is setup your production.rb file to point to Mandrill:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 25, # ports 587 and 2525 are also supported with STARTTLS
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, # detects and uses STARTTLS
    :user_name => "username",
    :password  => "password", # SMTP password is any valid API key
    :authentication => 'login', # Mandrill supports 'plain' or 'login'
    :domain => 'example.com', # your domain to identify your server when connecting
  }
```

So to summarize; in my opinion it's not a matter of volume, rather convenience.

I hope that helps.